# How can IntelliJ debugger disobey F7 (trace into)?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea

From time to time I meeting an issue, when I can't trace into some methods. I have breakpoint on method call, it is triggered, then I press `F7`, and then instead of tracing into the method, execution pointer just jumps to the next line.

Can general understanding of such situation be formulated?

I think this is somehow related to multithreading.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the source code to that code, and some debugger setting makes it skip without asking to download source or decompile, or maybe the call was to a native method?

Answer (score 1):

Try Alt-Shift-F7 (Force Step Into).

Maybe you are trying to step into JDK code?

There is a configurable list of ignored class/package names at:

File (menu) -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> Stepping -> Do not step into the classes